# How do I recreate the activity only once after opening the application?

Tags: android, kotlin, recreate

How do I recreate the activity only once after opening the application?

I tried to do this, but it didn't work. Endlessly recreate()

**refreshLang() in onCreate**

```
private fun refreshLang() {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).apply {
        val checkRun = getString("FIRSTRUN", "DEFAULT")
        if (checkRun == "YES") {
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this@MainActivity).edit().putString("FIRSTRUN", "NO").apply()
            recreate()
        }
    }
}
```

and *SharPref.putString("FIRSTRUN", "YES").apply()* in onDestroy to make it work again the next time you run it.

Comment: try replacing `(checkRun == "YES")` with `(checkRun.equals("YES"))`

Comment: Didn't help, it's the same thing, kind of.

Comment: Try calling refreshLang() with the checkRun condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer: Activity class
[recreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate())

It create new instance and initiates fresh activity lifecycle.

So when you call `recreate()` it will call `onCreate()` and will go in endless loop.

You have add some condition to avoid this overflow.

Edit:

Use `.equals` instead of ==

```
if ("YES".equals(checkRun)) {
   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this@MainActivity).edit().putString("FIRSTRUN", "NO").apply()
   recreate()
}
```

I suggest you not to use `recreate()`. It will call `onCreate` and `onDestory()`.

Refer below code.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        boolean recreateRequested = true;
        Intent currentIntent = getIntent();
        if (currentIntent.hasExtra("recreateRequested")){
            recreateRequested = currentIntent.getBooleanExtra("recreateRequested", true);
        }
        if (recreateRequested) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("recreateRequested", false);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Don't the conditions I wrote in the question solve this problem?

Comment: You should use .equals instead of ==.  Answer is edited.

Comment: It wont work if you put SharPref.putString("FIRSTRUN", "YES").apply()  in OnDestroy(). because recreate() ultimately call OnDestory()

Comment: Refer updated answer, if work please upvote and accept this answer

Comment: Yeah, it works, but in my case it didn't solve the problem. (Problem with switch locales)

Answer (score 1):

you can't compare two `String`s like this in your `if` condition

```
checkRun == "YES"
```

these are two separated instances of `String`, so they never be equal in the this meaning (`==` - same object)

use this instead

```
"YES".equals(checkRun)
```

`equals` will compare "content" of compared objects, in `String` case it will compare text

Answer (score -3):

use onResume Method

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
  
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: onResume() will trigger even after minimizing the application, and I need it to trigger only once, after **opening** the application.

Comment: Resume() is different than what recreate() does.